# After doing a while loop, check if there are any rows, if not, echo something PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a while loop that fetches rows from the MySQL database.

But I want to check if there are rows at all, if the table is empty, then echo an error.

I have a dirty way of doing this:

```
while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) $random[] = $row['a_column'] ) {
    if (count($random) == 0) {
    echo ' It's empty... ';
    } else {
echo $row['a_column'];
}
```

Problem is that I have many columns and I am sure this is an extremely dirty way of doing so..

**Problem**

I am using PDO and I am not really sure how would I check if there are any rows in the table..

**Question**

How would I find out that the table doesn't contains any rows, if it doesn't, echo error.. if it does, echo results of a_column?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$fetch->columnCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php). If there are no results it will return `0`. It also might be possible to use [`$fetch->rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), although the manual doesn't recommend it for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: If you use $fetch->columnCount() you will also have to add an extra query with SELECT COUNT(*) etc and it will actually be a weaker solution? Just using columnCount() will just retrieve the columns.

Comment: You don't need to do an extra query.

Comment: Do you mean that columnCount() returns the number of rows?

Comment: No, it returns the number of columns in the result set. So `SELECT username` will return `1`; `SELECT username, password` will return `2`, etc.

Comment: ahh ok, now I get it. If you don't have any columns return you will not have any rows returned?

Comment: Yes; if there are no rows returned by the query than `columnCount` will be `0`.

Comment: Yes, I know that... Hm. I read the question again. I thought it was about returning number of rows and not number of columns.  Sorry for bothering :-)

Comment: He only wants to know that there *are* rows, not how many there are. `columnCount` works fine for that. The problem with `rowCount` is that "For most databases, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not return the number of rows affected by a `SELECT` statement".

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it most straightforward way but for some reason you make it most complicated way.
What you really need is

- to get data from DB
- to check if you got any
- to use the data

so, here you go

```
 //to get data from DB
$data = $fetch->fetchAll();
//to check if you got any
if (!$data) {
    // It's empty
} else {
    // to use the data
    foreach ($data as $row){
        //use it
    }
}
```